# Вопрос об устройстве ОЗУ ЭВМ

Tags: железо, ram

Вопрос получился немного абстрактным, но я постараюсь максимально конкретизировать. Начну немного из далека, если позволите.

Все мы знаем, что ОЗУ состоит из некоторой совокупности регистров, а те, в свою очередь, представляют собой набор триггеров (простейшее электронное устройство, которое может принимать одно из двух устойчивых состояний). И тут сразу же возникает вопрос. Поскольку оперативная память является строго энергозависимой, то при каждом включении компьютера триггеры будут каждый раз принимать какое-то состояние, которое предусмотрено по умолчанию. Какое это состояние?

Если переходить от конкретного к абстрактному, то мы можем представить себе любой триггер в виде обычного двоичного разряда. Каждое из устойчивых состояний мы можем соотнести с еденицей или нулём. Так вот, какое положение понимают тригерры изначально? Они все обнуляются? Или же наоборот принимают значение 1? А может быть и вовсе всё происходит по какому-то псевдослучайному алгоритму? Очень хотелось бы знать!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Иногда делают отдельную линию сброса для всех триггеров. И, немного погодя после включения питания, на эту линию подают сигнал, и все триггеры сбрасываются в ноль. А иногда так не делают, и тогда все ОЗУ действительно заполняется случайными значениями. Для динамического ОЗУ, которое стоит сейчас в персоналках так и есть, то есть аппаратного сброса ОЗУ в ПК не предусмотрено. Но в персоналках после старта процессор программно очищает ОЗУ (чаще всего заполняет нулями). Для отладки ОЗУ иногда заполняется каким-то значением, отличным от нуля, чтобы отличить места, куда прошла запись. Но это уже забота конкретного отладчика.

UPD1:

> В общем, откуда берётся значение по умолчанию? Срабатывает обычное
>   присваивание значения по умолчанию нашей переменной? Или же просто
>   берётся участок памяти с изначально обнулёнными двоичными значениями и
>   этот ноль, который идёт вроде бы "по умолчанию", берётся именно
>   отсюда?

Не знаю как в Java, а в языке С/C++ статические переменные могут иметь и ненулевое значение. И в языке С/C++ статические переменные инициализируются либо при загрузке программы путем прописывания инициализирующих значений в специальный раздел программы. Либо (в случае старта программы из ROM) специальная инициализирующая подпрограмма (которая запускается до main) переносит из ROM в RAM инициализирующие значения для статических переменных.

К тому же в языке С++ статической переменной может быть объект класса с нетривиальным конструктором, который (например) может захватывать память в куче. И все эти конструкторы запускаются операционной системой до main. И они инициализируют свои области памяти явно ненулевыми значениями.

То есть в языке С/C++ не полагаются на изначальное обнуление части памяти, а процессор принудительно инициализирует память при загрузке программы.

Кроме того надо понимать, что физическая память в ПК общего назначения используется многократно разными программами. Например, Вы поработали с браузером, а потом запустили транслятор Visual Studio. Так как после работы браузера в RAM лежат какие-то числа, перед запуском Visual Studio RAM надо снова очистить. То есть если даже в начале работы компьютера память была инициализирована нулями, то в процессе работы память надо многократно переинициализировать для работы других программ.

UPD2:

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что во всех современных ЭВМ используется
>   именно DRAM?

В персоналках и мобильниках в качестве RAM используется DRAM. В компьютерах для специальных применений в качестве RAM может использоваться и статическая память. Она и быстрее и меньше потребляет мощности. Вплоть до того, что можно парковать компьютер и RAM будет сохранять все значения, питаясь от батарейки. И при включении питания работа начнется не с начальной загрузки, а с места останова. Например, многие системы защит в разных отраслях должны быть готовы к работе практически мгновенно после подачи питания. Тогда там применяют статическую память в качестве RAM.

UPD3:

> К примеру, у нас имеется следующая запись: public static int var = 5;
>
> Что именно здесь происходит? Я слышал такое интересное мнение, что
>   сначала полю var должно быть присвоено значение по умолчанию, то бишь
>   0, а затем уже будет присвоено значение 5, непосредственно как
>   результат операции присваивания. Это происходит по той причине, что
>   ноль присваивается ещё на этапе объявления переменной, а присваивание
>   через инициализатор идёт следующей операцией. А как оно происходит на
>   самом деле? Есть ли какое-то мнение по данному вопросу?

Если речь идет о персоналках и конкретно о системе Windows и трансляторе Visual Studio, то там **при загрузке программы** в память отведенную под var будет положено значение 5. Возможно, что перед загрузкой программы RAM дополнительно обнуляется системой, но для пользователя это недоступно и не имеет значения. Важно только то, что когда управление получает пользовательский main в переменной var лежит значение 5.

Чтобы разобраться в этом вопросе советую Вам написать простую программу на языке Си типа:

```
int var = 5;

int main(){
return var+1;
}
```

После этого оттранслировать эту программу на Вашем любимом трансляторе с ключом, который выводит ассемблерный листинг. И поглядеть, какие секции ассемблера формирует транслятор для статических переменных.

UPD4:

> В то же время, я получил ответ о том, что триггеры в структуре
>   динамической памяти с произвольным доступом не используются. В этом
>   случае возникает вполне резонный вопрос. Где же тогда физически
>   хранится вся информация? Как реализована бинарная концепция на
>   физическом уровне в данном случае? Благодарю!

Конденсаторы с динамическим обновлением ведут себя как триггеры. Так что Вы вполне можете считать, что DRAM построена на триггерах.

UPD5:

> @pepsicoca1 Да, но ведь конденсаторы с динамическим обновлением хоть и
>   ведут себя аналогичным с триггерами образом, но это всё равно не одно
>   и то же. Я так понимаю, что триггеры, как таковые, используется
>   непосредственно в SRAM? Я прав? – Lexoid 59 минут назад

Физически процессы в "честном" триггере и в конденсаторе с динамическим обновлением, конечно, разные. Но для программиста и DRAM и SRAM выглядят и ведут себя одинаково. Поэтому можно считать, что в DRAM организованы триггеры на конденсаторах, которые периодически перезаписываются незаметно для программиста. В конце концов триггер должен хранить свое значение и изменять его при записи, что с успехом делает конденсатор в DRAM. А как при этом физически организован триггер это совсем не важно. Например, кроме DRAM и SRAM существуют память на ЦМД. Также существует еще и Flash-память. Ячейки там ведут себя как триггеры, хотя физические процессы там кардинально отличаются от физических процессов и в DRAM и в SRAM и между собой.

Comment: Спасибо за хорошее объяснение! На этой почве у меня возник уже немного другой вопрос, если позволите. Давайте попытаемся экстраполировать всю эту ситуацию на один из языков программирования. Что я имею в виду? Сейчас постараюсь донести до Вас свою мысль! К примеру, возьмём довольно-таки популярный объектно-ориентированный язык программирования Java. Все мы прекрасно понимаем, что переменная в любом языке программирования является всего лишь абстракцией и представляет собой именованную (или же адресуемую любым другим образом) область памяти.

Comment: Поскольку язык программирования Java является языком со статической типизацией данных, мы указываем тип переменной ещё на этапе объявления. Для всех полей целочисленных типов существует значение по умолчанию, которое равно нулю. И мне всегда хотелось понять, почему всё происходит именно таким образом? Зависит ли это от особенностей оперативной памяти?

Comment: Я мыслю примерно следующим образом. При создании переменной мы просто резервируем место в памяти, которое ещё не использовалось. Если вся ОЗУ изначально «обнуляется», то мне становится понятно от куда берётся это значение. Или же память всё равно принудительно обнуляется повторно? Если это так, то такое поведение также вполне объяснимо. В этом случае мы обнуляем случайные значения, о которых Вы уже упоминали в своём комментарии.

Comment: В общем, откуда берётся значение по умолчанию? Срабатывает обычное присваивание значения по умолчанию нашей переменной? Или же просто берётся участок памяти с изначально обнулёнными двоичными значениями и этот ноль, который идёт вроде бы "по умолчанию", берётся именно отсюда?

Comment: наверное в большинстве языков при создании экземпляров классов указатели принимают значения Null, числа - 0, булевые типы false. В целом это поведение относится к ЯП и обычно документировано. То есть это для вас делает компилятор. К физическому состоянию каких-то ячеек памяти это отношения не имеет.

Comment: Насчёт статических переменных согласен с Вами. Они могут быть проинициализированы до непосредственного запуска самой программы (исполнения метода main()) при помощи обычного присваивания или статических блоков инициализации. С этим действительно всё понятно. А теперь хотелось бы снова уточнить один момент момент. Я так понимаю, что в С++ и Java в этом плане всё примерно одинаково, поскольку оба языка относятся к языкам со статической типизацией данных. К примеру, у нас имеется следующая запись: `public static int var = 5;`

Comment: Что именно здесь происходит? Я слышал такое интересное мнение, что сначала полю `var` должно быть присвоено значение по умолчанию, то бишь 0, а затем уже будет присвоено значение 5, непосредственно как результат операции присваивания. Это происходит по той причине, что ноль присваивается ещё на этапе объявления переменной, а присваивание через инициализатор идёт следующей операцией. А как оно происходит на самом деле? Есть ли какое-то мнение по данному вопросу?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Благодарю, теперь всё более-менее понятно!)

Comment: @teran А если мы присвоим значения нашим полям внутри конструктора? Будут ли в таком случае поля принимать свои значения по умолчанию? Или они примут именно те значения, которые мы им сами присвоим?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Да, но ведь конденсаторы с динамическим обновлением хоть и ведут себя аналогичным с триггерами образом, но это всё равно не одно и то же. Я так понимаю, что триггеры, как таковые, используется непосредственно в SRAM? Я прав?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы не стал сравнивать DRAM c тригером, там просто транзистор и конденсатор, т.е. при включении вся память содержит только нулевые значения, в разделе WIKI по DRAM это всё хорошо описанно.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что во всех современных ЭВМ используется именно DRAM?

Comment: На самом деле не транзистор и конденсатор, а "емкость" и транзистор, где емкость может быть самим транзистором и представлена (полевые транзисторы, например).

Comment: @smellyshovel Хорошо, а где же тогда непосредственно триггеры используются?

Comment: @Lexoid не понял, к чему это. В других типах памяти?

Comment: @smellyshovel Да, именно это я и имел в виду.

Comment: В принципе тригеры используются в SRAM, и это приводит к тому что при включении SRAM содержит произвольные данные

Answer (score 0):

> Поскольку оперативная память является строго энергозависимой, то при каждом включении компьютера триггеры будут каждый раз принимать какое-то состояние, которое предусмотрено по умолчанию. Какое это состояние?

Поставлен конкретный вопрос о конкретном электронном устройстве.

Ответ так же конкретен, хотя он вас и вряд ли устроит - **неопределенное**.

Триггеры - это полупроводниковые устройства. Чтобы определить, какое из двух полупроводниковых устройств работает быстрее другого (чисто физически), необходимо произвести соответствующие замеры. Очевидно, что сделать это не представляется возможным (да и не является нужным), учитывая размеры современных п/п приборов.

Быстродействие одного транзистора может отличаться от быстродействия другого всего на доли наносекунд. И именно эти доли и являются определяющим фактором. Разумеется, что внешние условия могут также оказывать влияние, однако если этим фактором пренебречь, а также сократить количество самих транзисторов (чтобы еще сильнее снизить вероятность случайного поведения), то случайность становится вовсе не случайностью, и если вы возьмете 10 триггеров (в виде дискретных элементов), то с наибольшей вероятностью они всегда будут принимать одни и те же состояния при включении (например из транзисторов A и B первым сработает B; из C и D - C, и т.д.), что говорит о чисто физической природе происходящего.

Comment: Интересное мнение. Думаю, что Вы правы. Но с другой стороны, как мне кажется, я сам уже немного запутался. Я выяснил, что в современных реалиях преимущественно используется компьютерная память типа DRAM. Это справедливо как для персональных ЭВМ, так и для большинства мобильных устройств. В то же время, я получил ответ о том, что триггеры в структуре динамической памяти с произвольным доступом не используются. В этом случае возникает вполне резонный вопрос. Где же тогда физически хранится вся информация? Как реализована бинарная концепция на физическом уровне в данном случае? Благодарю!

Comment: Пожалуй, замечу, что большинство контроллеров DDR сейчас поддерживают ECC (Error Correction (Control) Codes). Так вот, в таком контроллере обычно есть функция инициализации, которая вызывается при включении системы (на стадии работы firmware) в результате чего память становится valid (не уверен, что все контроллеры ее обнуляют). Если же эту функцию не вызывать и начать читать память  по адресам, в которые еще не было записи, то возникает ошибка чтения (некорректный ECC)

Comment: @avp стадия инициализации - это уже программная часть, я же говорю исключительно об аппаратной. А так - скорее всего так и есть. Не спорю, потому что в тонкости не вдавался

Comment: @Lexoid вопрос был задан конкретно о памяти на триггерах, и конкретно о триггерах я Вам и отвечаю. Остальное - разновидности, SRAM, DRAM - каждый имеет свои особенности и строение.

Comment: @Lexoid Где же тогда физически хранится вся информация? - Очевидно, в виде заряда на емкости. Есть один транзистор, представляющий "ноль", и другой, представляющий "единицу". При этом сами "циферки" представлены в виде заряда: заряд либо на одном, либо на другом, следовательно в ячейке памяти либо единица, либо ноль.

Comment: Уточню насчет этой части: "заряд либо на одном, либо на другом". Именно потому, что триггер.

Comment: @smellyshovel, побольше бы аппаратуры, которая сразу при подаче питания включается в нужном для ОС состоянии... (Я уже не говорю, что на некоторые устройства (в т.ч. CPU, которые видят обычные программисты  (конечно, это зависит от организации системы в целом)) и само питание подается в процессе работы программ в сервисном процессоре)

Comment: @avp по сути опять же смотря о чем мы говорим. Если мы говорим о SRAM, то там да, изначально ячейки находятся в (псевдо)произвольном состоянии. Если же речь идет о DRAM, то там, вроде как, такого не наблюдается. Но в целом согласен, думаю, было бы намного проще, если бы программно обнулять память на стадии инициализации не приходилось.